# how to use exists in this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a patient called Joseph in a table.
I need to get the info of all doctors that attend him.
The database is like this:

Doctors table:

```
-ID
-NAME
-AGE
-SPECIALTY
```

Patient table:

```
-ID 
-NAME
-AGE
-SICKNESS
```

Appointments:

```
-doctor_ID
-patient_ID
-DATE
```

It is mandatory that I use exists to get the data

Our work is the nearly the same as the answer given below. It goes like this

```
SELECT doctor.name, doctor.age
  FROM clinic.doctors
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM clinic.appointments
               WHERE appointments.patient_ID = '1'
                 AND appointments.doctors_ID <> NULL
             )
```

Comment: Provide structures as CREATE TABLE. Provide sample data as INSERT INTO. Show desired result for this data.

Comment: Do you know joseph's ID already, or only his name? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes I know his ID. Yes this is homework

Comment: So, you want all the `doctors` records where an `appointments` record exists, for that doctor and the patient called Joseph *(who's ID you know)*?  What have you tried already?  Have you even checked the syntax for `EXISTS()`?  *(Or are you just expecting people on the internet to spoon feed you answers to your homework, so that you don't have to do it?)*

Comment: Me and my classmates have been trying for a week, we cannot find a solution and we have tried our best, the deadline is for tomorrow.

Comment: ***What have you already tried***?  If you post an example of SQL that you tried, and a description of why it didn't give the results you need, then we can see your effort ***and*** explain the mistakes you made as well as how to fix them.  Asking for the answer with none of that rarely gets positive responses.

Comment: The first comment has covered all this already.

Comment: EXISTS not needed in this task. At all.

Comment: *"Me and my classmates have been trying for a week"*: show your work.

Comment: @Akina true, but it might be academic demonstration of EXISTS understanding

Comment: Yes it's mandatory

Comment: Our work is the nearly the same as the answer given below. It goes like this SELECT doctor.name, doctor.age
FROM
  clinic.doctors
WHERE
  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM clinic.appointments WHERE appointments.patient_ID = '1' AND appointments.doctors_ID <> NULL)

Comment: Closed for refusal to show existing attempts.  Re-open available should the OP edit the question and show the SQL they have tried, including details of how their efforts failed to give the results they require.

Comment: "Our work is the nearly the same as the answer given below. It goes like this"—"nearly" the same? How is it different? Specifically, how does it fail to do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general form for coordinating an exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  table_whose_records_I_want_to_know x
WHERE
  EXISTS(SELECT null FROM table_whose_records_might_relate_to_x y WHERE x.some_column = y.some_column)
```

Think of it like "for every record in X the DB will run the subquery using the values from that row in X, and if the subquery produces at least one row, then X's row will be present in the output. If the subquery produces no rows, then X row is not output". It doesnt matter what values the sub query selects - EXISTS merely cares whether the subquery produces any rows or not, not what values are produced

You thus need to make your query like "select all from doctors where there exists a row in apointments that has a doctor_id of the doctor's id and a patient_id of Z" where Z is the ID you claim to know

---

Edit: Just to make it absolutely super clear how the subquery is coordinated with the outer query table:

[image]

All the attempts you've posted that you've tried so far do not coordinate the subquery at all

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work, what we did was SELECT doctors.name, doctors.age
FROM
  clinic.doctors
WHERE
  EXISTS(SELECT null FROM clinic.appointments WHERE appointments.patients_ID = '1') It returns all doctors and not he only ones I want

Comment: *You thus need to make your query like "select all from doctors where there exists a row in apointments **that has a doctor_id of the doctor's id** and a patient_id of Z" where Z is the ID you claim to know*

Comment: *It returns all doctors and not he only ones I want* - it's because there really is a row where patient_id is 1. Nothing in the query you've written coordinates(connects) the subquery with the doctor's table